# How to get Constructor Parameter Name in C#

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I was wondering how to get the parameter name "kernel" from the default constructor for the DataAccess.

```
_kernel.Get<DataAccess>(new Parameter("kernel", _kernel, true));
```

I would like to avoid these "magic strings" and get something like:

```
_kernel.Get<DataAccess>(new Parameter(DataAccess.Constructor.kernel, _kernel, true));
```

Regards

Comment: any reason why you can't use `nameof`?

Comment: Assuming it's the only constructor, you can get the name using Reflection: `typeof(DataAccess).GetConstructors()[0].GetParameters()[0].Name`

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama, `nameof` can't be used to get the parameter name

Comment: @haim770 Hmm this expression that you wrote is interesting but in the case that we change the order of the params it would break. The solution works, but I would like to have something cleaner. :D Thank you

Comment: @IgorJakovljevic, I agree it's far from ideal. Ideally, Ninject would have to match the argument you're passing to the matching constructor.

Comment: Do you have to supply the dependency using a Parameter? The alternative would be to let Ninject resolve it for you. I mostly use parameters for simple data types, e.g. string, int etc.

Comment: @AndreasAppelros Could you maybe share the solution for the Ninject resolution? As far as I know you have to provide the name of the parameter. Maybe as an answer, that way if it works I can flag this qustion as answered. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, you haven't explained why you need to use named parameters. You should not need to supply the kernel as a parameter, for example. It is bound to `IKernel` by default, so if your `DataAccess`class looks like:

```
public class DataAccess {
    public DataAccess(IKernel kernel) {
    }
}
```

then a call to `Get` should inject the kernel automatically:

```
_kernel.Get<DataAccess>();
```

That said, it is considered bad practice to inject the kernel, see [Service Locator antipattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). Instead inject the dependencies you would get from the kernel instead, like this:

```
public class DataAccess {
    public DataAccess(IMyDependency myDependency, ...) {
    }
}
```

and let ninject resolve the dependency by binding it:

```
_kernel.Bind<IMyDependency>().To<MyDependency>();
```